# An unnatural context for "even"

Tags: word-usage

While playing a game, I stumbled upon a sentence containing a usage of "even" that left me quite confused. The sentece said:

> "Hey, it's me, Mallow! That's a fine Revival Herb! Its bitter bite is
>   even a shock to Pokémon, but that's what will add depth to the
>   flavor!"

I understand the meaning of the word "even" but here it sounds weird. Wouldn't the sentence sound more natural if it said:

> "Its bitter bite is a shock even to Pokémon, but that's what will add depth to the flavor!" ?

I'm aware that my question is really vague and perhaps it has more to do with style than grammar, but there is something about that sentence which sounds really off to me

Answer (score 1):

As an adverb, there can be options where to place it. Either example is OK.

> Its bitter bite is **even** a shock to Pokémon

indicates the "shock" was surprising.

> Its bitter bite is a shock **even** to Pokémon

emphasizes the impact on Pokemon.